# How can I make ListPlot use my iteration as the x coord?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, syntax

I have some code that takes a list of energies, plugs them into a set of recursion relations and numerically solves for each energy (15 energies total) and for each n(modes, 21 total)

```
\[HBar] = 1;
m = 1;

Do[Energy[z] = 0.5 + 2 z, {z, 0, 14}]
Table[Energy[z], {z, 0, 14}];
Do[Entot[n, o] = Energy[o] - \[HBar]*\[Omega]*n, {n, -10, 10}, {o, 0, 
  14}]
Do[k[n, o] = 2*m*(Entot[n, o])^(1/2), {n, -10, 10}, {o, 0, 14}]

\[Omega] = 1;
s = 10;
k0 = -6;
\[Alpha] = 4;
t0 = 1;
t[-11] = 0.01;
t[11] = 0.01;
r[-11] = 0.01;
r[11] = 0.01;
ClearAll[plot1]
Do[eqn[n, o] = -t[n] + 
KroneckerDelta[n, 
     1] + (s*m/(2*\[HBar]^2*I*k[n, o]))*(t[n - 1] + 
       t[n + 1]), {n, -10, 10}, {o, 0, 14}];
tab1 = Table[eqn[n, o], {o, 0, 14}, {n, -10, 10}];
tab2 = Table[t[n], {n, -10, 10}];

Do[plot1[p] = NSolve[tab1[[p]] == 0, tab2], {p, 1, 15}]
Do[f[n, o] = t[n] /. plot1[o], {n, -10, 10}, {o, 1, 15}]
ListPlot[Abs[
  Table[Flatten[Table[f[n, o], {n, -10, 10}]], {o, 1, 15}]], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}]
```

The problem is I need the ListPlot to use the values {n,-10,10} as the x values rather than the index of the list. 
I tried doing

```
ListPlot[Abs[
  Table[Flatten[Table[{n,f[n, o]}, {n, -10, 10}]], {o, 1, 15}]], 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}]
```

but I think there's a problem with the syntax and the list manipulation.

Comment: Is the `DataRange` option inadequate to your needs?

Comment: I don't think that's what I need, I virtually just need my graph to shift to the left by 11

Comment: You can explicitly put the value in the list like `Table[{n,Abs[f[n, o]]}, {n, -10, 10}]`  (you will need to tell `Flatten` to just flatten one level, `Flatten[Table[],1]` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure `DataRange` does what you want.  I also changed the computation to more standard WL usage.

```
ClearAll[energy, entot, kt, tt]
\[HBar] = 1; m = 1;
energy = Array[0.5 + 2 # &, 15, 0];
entot = Outer[#2 - \[HBar]*\[Omega]*#1 &, Range[-10, 10], energy];
k = 2*m*entot^(1/2);
tab2 = Array[t[#] &, 21, -10];
tt = Array[t[# - 1] + t[# + 1] &, 21, -10];
eqnNew = -tab2 + ((s*m/(2*\[HBar]^2*I))/knew)*tt;
eqnNew[[12]] += 1;
tab1 = Transpose@eqnNew;
\[Omega] = 1; s = 10; t[-11] = 0.01; t[11] = 0.01;
data = Abs[ReplaceAll[tab2, #] & /@ (NSolve[tab1[[#]] == 0, tab2] & /@ Range[15])];
g1 = Labeled[ListPlot[Flatten[data, 1], PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}], 
   "Old Range", Top];
g2 = Labeled[ListPlot[Flatten[data, 1], PlotRange -> {0, 1.5},
    DataRange -> {-10, 10}], "New Range", Top];
```

Effect:

[image]

Comment: Excellent thank you!